# how to fire change event on select emberjs

Tags: ember.js

The behavior that i want is when changing the select is to save it's model

I though about using observable, but i have another problem

my view looks something like this

```
{{#each item in model.Items}}
<div class="select">
  {{view Ember.Select 
    content=typesLookup
    selection=type
    prompt="Select Type"
  }}
</div>
{{/each}}
```

so if i went with the observables solution, what i want is to also know the specific item that has changed to update it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add the observer and selection on an itemController.

```
App.FooController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  type:undefined,
  watchType: function(){
    console.log('this model changed', this.get('model'));
  }.observes('type')
});

{{#each item in model.Items itemController='foo'}}
  <div class="select">
    {{view Ember.Select 
      content=typesLookup
      selection=item.type
      prompt="Select Type"
    }}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Can you save without an observer in the controller?  Could you have an action in the view's js file that saves the records type 'onChange' or something like that?

Comment: Sure, though both views and controllers are being deprecated in Ember 2.0, essentially they'll get merged into one place called component.  But from the view you can access the controller, which has access to the model, where you could save it.